# How to run a separate internet connection between two switches over fiber

Tags: cisco

At my office we currently have a data center where our corporate connection runs from a core switch over a fiber connection to a closet with a few switches in it on the other side of the building. I was wondering if it is possible to also run our external internet connection(cablevision modem) over the fiber as well so we can plug an Access point in on the other side of the building for that connection.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what VLANs are for.

Comment: Ok, so I see how to create a vlan, assign it a static IP address, and assign interfaces to that vlan, but I am confused about how to connect the external connection from the cable modem to the core switch so that the new vlan I create is associated with this connection.

Comment: There are a thousand ways to screw this up. I would *highly* suggest hiring someone to come in and help you out with this. It's far too broad for any of us to venture a guess at without knowing the details of your network topology and configuration.

Comment: Umm... I don't understand why you need to do this. You have internet access via your connection to the closet switche, which then connect to the core switch, which then connect to the modem, no? If so, then just connect an AP to one of your closet switches.

Comment: We already have a connection in place, this would be for a separate modem that we can use for external testing outside of our corporate network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure out how to get this setup. Essentially I just had to create a vlan, and assign an interface to that vlan which I connected the cable modem to, then I added that vlan to the trunk and on the other end of the trunk I added an interface to that vlan I created and attached a wifi access point to it, assigned a static ip, and it worked like a charm. I had tried this setup a couple times with no luck before I was realized the issue was that I had another connection from that same cable modem going to the switch, once this was removed it worked fine